# How do I blend two materials with a texture map?

Tags: texturing, materials

It's not what you would normally think. I want to know how to blend materials to have their own settings like metallic glossiness, roughness, things like that. I used to use 3DS Max and the way it blends materials is by using a black and white texture map like so.

Here's the diffuse texture

[image]

And here's where I would want to put different material settings on the parts of the texture.

[image]

And here's what the model looks like

[image]

Would this be possible in Blender?

Comment: you can use your B&W image as a mask in Blender as well, for example you can mix 2 Principled BSDF (each will have a different setting) with a Mix Shader, and use the Image Texture node with the b&w image as the factor of the Mix Shader

Comment: @moonboots Can I get some images please? I'm still a bit new to advance material linking stuff. I see where I can use the mask image as a factor but, the where to put the other principled BSDF?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the kind of material you can set: Mix 2 *Principled BSDF* through a *Mix Shader*, use the b&w image as the factor of the *Mix Shader*, plug your color image into the 2 *Principled BSDF*, set the *Principled BSDF* the way you want, for example you can give a *Metallic* value of 1 to the *Principled BSDF* that is supposed to display the gold area, etc:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I got it now.